# Can't post. Error message

Tags: support

I'm trying to post this (http://pastie.org/10697702) question but I'm getting this:
[image]

Comment: Firefox 44.
I restarted the browser and it worked.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35039002/how-to-encode-an-associative-array-grouping-one-of-its-members
Thanks!

Comment: Firefox.... use a decent browser will you. I heard Internet Explorer is pretty popular ;)